# Android average memory limit

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I was wondering what the average memory limit that smartphones have. I am creating quite an heavy game with many Bitmaps and I load and unload between loadingscreens (menu > gameplay). But one of our testphones have 32mb memory limit, is that normal or is that rare?

At my loadingscreen I am calculating how large the image to be loaded is and only load it if there is enough memory, otherwise wait for the garbage collector. But if there isn't any more to collect I restart the load and load them with less quality (16b).

But if it's only a rare case that smartphones nowdays have 32mb memory limit  I wouldn't mind loading the images with less quality but if there is 20-30% that has that low amount I would instead rather optimize to use less and smaller images.

So the question is, is it only a rare case that smartphones today only have 32mb memory limit, or is there some kind of statistics of memory limits on smartphones?

Comment: A device may have memory as low as 16MB

Comment: Yes I know, but they will get the lower quality images. But I was wondering if I should optimize images for the devices that has 32mb limit.

Comment: I would say it is rare, though the amount of memory will vary wildly. In my experience, 512MB is the lowest for _most_ smartphones available today.

Comment: I mean the amount of memory limit per application

Answer (score -3):

I think there is a limit on the amount of memory that an application can use.Used to be 32MB... There might be a permission that you can change to request more memory, in the same way that you can request hardware acceleration. From a quick google android:largeHeap="true" might be your answer... Also Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

Comment: The largeHeap is for the newer android versions and I wouldn't want to exclude devices that uses older versions of android. My Target is 2.2+

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.